# Javascript looping, using array keys as condition statements - possible?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, key, dxf

Is there a way to specify array index key positions so that I can use them as conditional statements in a javascript loop?

I have a string of coordinates, that keeps growing every time the user selects a grid polygon on a map. I take the string & turn it into an array. I am building a text file (dxf format) and as such I have separated the header info, the closing info & made other variables of key positions:

```
var oneUnit = (coord_array[0])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[1])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[2])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[3])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[2])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[3])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[4])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[5])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[4])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[5])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[6])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[7])+'\r\n  0\r\nLINE\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n  6\r\nCONTINUOUS\r\n 62\r\n1\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[6])+'\r\n 20\r\n'+(coord_array[7])+'\r\n 11\r\n'+(coord_array[8])+'\r\n 21\r\n'+(coord_array[9])+'\r\n  0\r\nTEXT\r\n  8\r\nUnit\r\n 10\r\n'+(coord_array[0])+'\r\n  20\r\n'+(coord_array[1])+'\r\n  40\r\n85.0\r\n  1\r\n'+(name_array[0])+'\r\n';
```

I have done this for a user selection of 3 units -so my index has grown to 29.

How do I construct a loop that will specify keys so that the code produces a specific return?

```
if (coord_array = i > 9 + < 20 ) {
download_file('data.dxf', 'text/dxf', (dxfHeader)+(oneUnit)+(twoUnit)+(dxfCloser));
}
else if (coord_array = i > 20 < 30 ) {
download_file('data.dxf', 'text/dxf', (dxfHeader)+(oneUnit)+(twoUnit)+(threeUnit)+(dxfCloser));
}
else { 
download_file('data.dxf', 'text/dxf', (dxfHeader)+(oneUnit)+(dxfCloser));

}
```

If anyone has tried this - or knows of a more elegant way of dealing with this - I would be happy to hear about it.

It does work somewhat but my condition statements are faulty as when I try picking three grid units, it returns only the first file (which is populating only two) - and for the last creates extra coordinates as undefined.....

Comment: `If` boolean expressions like `(coord_array = i > 9 + < 20 )` are not valid JavaScript. Please correct the syntax and also explain "so my index has grown to 29 " - what index and where does 29 come from? It is hard to understand what you are asking about.

Comment: Pelase  format the `var oneUnit = ...` line. It's unreadable.

Comment: Sorry traktor53 - if the user picks 3 units, each unit has 10 items - therefor the array grows to an index of [0] to [29]. Using this 3 unit example, I am looking to see what the syntax should be to create the loop that will select the right number of sections of dxf code based on how many user pick there are.